# Optimize Django Queryset Many to Many for loop with prefetch_related

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

i got a function on view that execute 64 querys in 4.5 seconds, so i have to optimize for a better performance.

The problem is prefetch_related doesnt work as i expected, so i have a new queryset for every iteration on the for loop.

here is the model.

[image]

```
class Carrera(models.Model):
'''Carreras de cada sede'''
codigo = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=300)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.codigo} - {self.nombre}"


class EstandarProducto(models.Model):
''''''
costo_unitario_uf = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=5, default=0)
cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=0)
total_uf = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=5, default=0)
recinto = models.ForeignKey(Recinto, related_name='estandares_producto', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
producto = models.ForeignKey(
    Producto, related_name='estandares_producto', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
proveedor = models.ForeignKey(
    Proveedor, related_name='estandares_producto', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
carreras = models.ManyToManyField(Carrera, related_name="estandares_productos", blank=True)
```

And here is my views:

```
class getEstandarPorRecinto(APIView):

@query_debugger
def get(self, request, format=None):
    id_recinto = request.GET.get('recinto')
    id_sede = request.GET.get('sede')
    estandares = EstandarProducto.objects.select_related('recinto','producto','proveedor').prefetch_related(Prefetch('carreras')).filter(recinto=id_recinto)
    inventario = InventarioProducto.objects.select_related('inventario').filter(inventario__sede=id_sede)
    num_salas = SedeRecinto.objects.select_related('sede').filter(sede=id_sede, recinto=id_recinto)[0].numero_salas
    productos_en_inventario = inventario.values() 
    lista_enviar = []

    for estandarProducto in estandares:
        carreras = []
        for carrera in estandarProducto.carreras.values():
            print("Codigo: " ,carrera.get("codigo"))
            carreras.append(carrera.get("codigo"))
        cantidad_inventario = 0
        año_compra = ""
        id_inventario_producto = ""
        print("Carreras: ",carreras)
        for producto in productos_en_inventario: 
            if producto.get("id") == estandarProducto.producto.id: 
                cantidad_inventario = producto.get("cantidad") 
                año_compra = producto.get("ultimo_año_reposicion") 
                id_inventario_producto = producto.get("id") 

        
        estandar_json = {
            "id_producto": estandarProducto.producto.id, 
            "id_estandar_producto": estandarProducto.id, 
            "codigo": estandarProducto.producto.codigo, 
            "carreras": carreras, 
            "categoria": estandarProducto.producto.categoria, 
            "nombre": estandarProducto.producto.nombre, 
            "descripcion": estandarProducto.producto.descripcion, 
            "cantidad_esperada": estandarProducto.cantidad,
            "proveedor_id": estandarProducto.proveedor.id, 
            "proveedor": estandarProducto.proveedor.nombre, 
            "frecuencia_reposicion": estandarProducto.producto.frecuencia_reposicion, 
            "inventario_producto_id": id_inventario_producto, 
            "costo_un_uf": estandarProducto.costo_unitario_uf, 
            "total_uf": estandarProducto.total_uf, 
            "tipo_presupuesto": estandarProducto.producto.tipo_presupuesto, 
            "inventario": cantidad_inventario, 
            "ultimo_año_compra": año_compra, 
            "numero_salas": num_salas, 
            "a_comprar": estandarProducto.cantidad*num_salas 
        }
        
        lista_enviar.append(estandar_json)
    data = lista_enviar
    return Response(data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The problem is on the line:

```
estandares = EstandarProducto.objects.select_related('recinto','producto','proveedor').prefetch_related(Prefetch('carreras')).filter(recinto=id_recinto)
```

and

```
for carrera in estandarProducto.carreras.values():
    print("Codigo: " ,carrera.get("codigo"))
    carreras.append(carrera.get("codigo"))
```

how i can get all the carreras.codigo on a single query, for then append on the list carreras[]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [**`docs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

> any subsequent chained methods which imply a different database query will ignore previously cached results, and retrieve data using a fresh database query.

This means that the `values()` call essentially makes your prefetch unusable, and will cause your for loop to hit the database to satisfy the `values()` call. In that case just use `all()` and get `codigo` from the instance itself like this:

```
    for estandarProducto in estandares:
        carreras = []
        for carrera in estandarProducto.carreras.all():
            carreras.append(carrera.codigo)
```

But it seems you only need the `codigo` themselves, so @pouria farhadi's answer would work well.

Comment: im still getting the same amount of queries with both answers.

Comment: Can you update with the current changes you have and also if possible add how you count the queries

Comment: sorry i reloader bad, i use your code and know i just got 6 querys in 0.62 seconds! Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `values_list` and set `flat` True to give list output

for example:

```
carreras  = estandares.values_list("carreras__codigo", flat=True)
```